# Stereo Mix does not work

Tags: audio-streaming

Stereo Mix no longer seems to work on my computer -- it did once in windows xp, but now I am unable to receive any sort of audio from it. When trying to record it with programs such as **Virtual Audio Streaming**, it reports that there is an error opening the sound device. Additionally, I can make no changes whatsoever to Stereo Mix, such as with regards to default format, where it simply reports Format not supported by device

Comment: Stereo Mix is a software?

Comment: You probably upgraded your sound card drivers, and this channel is no longer available.